# Getting difference betwen 2 dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 dates which is start date and end date
let's say start date is 07/01/2015 and end date is 12/31/2017 so, difference is 2 years and 6 month but i need output as 2.5 years

How can I get output as 2.5 years?

Comment: and a questions is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select DateDiff(DD,'07/01/2015','12/31/2017')/365.0
```

Returns

```
2.504109
```

Comment: Thanks @John Cappelletti... This is what I wants to do. Thank you very much again.

Comment: @F.Patel Happy to help